# Why is my 3-speed fan only working at 2 speeds after replacing parts?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a 3 speed ceiling fan with a wall switch.  I mostly use the middle speed throughout the day and at night (I'm always hot). I had a brief power surge last weekend and the fan would only work on the highest speed (which is way too fast and noisy).  I did some digging and found that it could be the capacitor.  So I cracked it open and found it.

[image]

I went to the amazon machine and ordered this:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A3KHCE4?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A3KHCE4)
(The photo says 250VAC, but the actual cap is 450VAC)

I put this in, and ... well now it seems I have high speed and low speed but no medium speed.  This seems like progress, but I am uncertain.

Looking for advice on what might be the problem and solution. I really don't want to replace the unit as it's over my bed and very high (15') so it's a giant inconvenience.

Thank you!

EDIT:

The blue wire goes to the light fixture that I previously removed to get to the capacitor.

Moving my bed to replace the fan is non-trivial
[image]

Comment: You ordered a different part than was originally installed and are surprised that it's not working to the original spec? Also, is there indication that the blue wire to the left of the picture was supposed to be attached to the device in the middle? Did you attempt to attach it to the new one? What lead you to believe this part was bad? Also, you were able to get up there to replace this part, so it's not entirely unreasonable to get up there to replace the whole fan - keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: You need to figure out where that blue wire should be. No design would leave a loose wire like that.

Comment: @FreeMan there's a big difference between lifting a capacitor down from that height, and lifting a big fan, in particular as you can get away with an imperfect ladder placement when the weight is small, but not for something heavy.

Comment: @FreeMan Wow. Okay. First, the capacitor is the same rating 5uF and +/5%. The VAC rating isn't relative here because the new one can handle MORE. It doesn't change the functionality.  Secondly, the blue wire goes to the light.  I removed the light fixture and photo'd the capacitor.   Yes, I could stand on my bed and remove the capacitor. But the fan fixture is another 10' to the ceiling and the motor weighs significantly more than a capacitor.  Dang, you read my post and instantly knew everything.

Comment: @ChrisH I had taken the entire thing apart. The blue wire goes to the light fixture.  The photos shows the cap before I removed the cap. And yeah, I can stand on the bed and get to the bottom of the fixture. There's no way I can change this whole thing from the bed. So I have to completely move the bed (which is no small task. Plus, being up on a tall ladder and pulling down a heavy motor isn't fun - but I can do it

Comment: No sir, I don't know everything, that's why I asked a bunch of questions. If I had all your answers for you, I'd have written an answer. Also, the little `2` next to my questions indicate that at least 2 other people had similar questions. If you take offence just because someone asks you for clarification, well, it's _your_ fault for _taking_ offence.

Comment: @FreeMan 
I didn't take offence for your questions - your assumptions "Seems like you can get up there to me" - without knowing the physical situation. And now that I've clarified - Got any advice?

Comment: Staring your comment with "Wow. Okay." indicated to me that you'd taken offense. My apologies for the misunderstanding. Unfortunately, no, I don't have further suggestions for you. When my ceiling fans have died, I've gone down the "replace" route, not "repair" path. My ceilings are only 10', so working from a ladder (or standing on the bed) has been manageable. Your situation is different. You _may_ have to bite the bullet at some point though, so just tuck that away in the back of your mind to be prepared...

Comment: @FreeMan What doesn't make sense to me - is that the motor works on fast and (now) a low mode.    So, the motor itself is good.  I ordered another capacitor - because changing the switch didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

whats up with the blue wire?? it was connected to something or it wouldn't be bare conductor showing. i would suggest replacing the 3 speed switch. seems as if one of the switch levels is fried due to the surge. assuming you replaced the capacitor with the same size and type capacitor. could be a loose wire also. very easy to bump one loose when you were changing the cap. check your connections and wiring first, replace switch 2nd, and if neither of those fix what ails ya...ya need a new fan motor

Comment: Warren Mclaughlin 
Blue wire is to the light, I previously removed.  I hadn't considered the 3 way switch. Thanks! I will definitely check that out.

Comment: I tried the switch, but no avail. Still only working on 2 speeds.